# Class outline in XCode

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, editor

I am looking for a XCode plugin or some configuration settings that might allow me to see the class structure in a file, by showing all defined classes, variables and functions on the right hand side of the screen much like Eclipse. An example of the same for vim can be found [here](http://majutsushi.github.io/tagbar/). I work in both C++ and Objective-C and would like something that would work with either language. The screenshot of eclipse below demonstrates what I am talking about.

[image: Eclipse Screenshot]

Can some one point me to such a pluign or how this can be done using the XCode settings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd> to get the list of all functions in XCode currently opened page

OR

You may press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> shortcut and then press the 2 icons at the bottom as shown in the image below.

[image]

Comment: @subzero It that what your looking for?

Comment: yes.... is there any way to make this appear permanently on the screen in the right hand side?